# Using RRT* from OMPL as global planner in ROS

Tags: ros, base-global-planner, ros-kinetic, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use RRT* as global planner for my turtlebot. Should I reinvent the wheel by writing the algorithms myself from scratch (as a plugging) as suggested here:  https://answers.ros.org/question/320619/how-can-i-change-the-default-global-path-planning-algorithm-a-and-dijkstra-into-my-custom-path-planner-rrt/

or can I use something like OMPL, if yes, how ?  I read something about ompl_ros_interface, but in the documentation page it is said that ompl_ros_interface is not available for Kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336064/using-rrt*-from-ompl-as-global-planner-in-ros/) by [kiko453](https://answers.ros.org/users/45196/kiko453/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good news, someone did it for you

https://github.com/ykarmesh/RRT-Plugin

And if its not quite what you're looking for, it'll at least get you 80% there.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0